# Google Visualization Charts not displaying in Firefox only

Tags: firefox, google-visualization, ssl-certificate

I came across this issue the other day, I have been using the Google Visualization API specifically for a chart.

Everything was working in Chrome and IE but when trying to view the page in Firefox the chart would not display.

I did receive an error in the Firefox developer tools:

> ReferenceError: google is not defined

This is from code that looked like this,

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

As I mentioned above, this was working on other browsers(IE, Chrome) just not Firefox.
Why is the chart not showing in Firefox only? Why is google no longer defined in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, the issue was caused by un-trusted SSL certificates in my Firefox browser.

As many of us know Firefox does not use the same certificate store as the other browsers that I mentioned.

For this instance the Google certificate was not being trusted. Once the certificate was added as an exception the grid and page functioned as expected.

(For a little more information, the certificate from Google was not being trusted because of network security software)